# event.preventDefault not working for a specific call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an icon that is placed over another image and on click I want it to remove the div is its parent.  I have achieved this functionality, but the jquery function I am using is not preventing default like I have specified (it takes you to the top of the page to the "#" href).  I am not sure why.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<article class="boxBg" id="box-{{$like->id}}">
<div class="image-height">
<a href="#" class="remove-artist"><i id="all-{{$like->id}}" class="remove fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a>
<a href="/artists/{{$like->id}}" title="image"><img src="{{$like->image_path}}" width="260" height="159" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
</article>
```

//JQuery

```
$(".remove-artist").click(function(event) {

      var id = $(this).find("i.fa-times").attr('id');

      request = $.ajax({ 
      url: "/artists/faremove", 
      type: "post", success:function(data){}, 
      data: {'id': id} ,beforeSend: function(data){console.log(data);} 
      });

      var likeid = id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');

      $("#box-"+likeid).hide("slow");

      event.preventDefault;

});
```

relevant CSS:

```
.image-height {
    height: 159px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

    .remove-artist {
        position:absolute;
        right:5px;
        top:5px;
    }

    .image-height i.remove {
        color:#000000 !important;
        display:none;
    }

    .image-height:hover i.remove {

        display:block;
    }
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use,

```
event.preventDefault();
```

instead of

```
event.preventDefault;
```

Because `.preventDefault()` is a `function` not a `property` of `event` object

Answer (score 1):

Try as shown below ..

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Its a function you need to add () at the end.

For more information check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the link.[click here]

> event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

You 're missing `()` for `.preventDefault()` method:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault` is a function which you'll have to call. To call a function with no paramters, you need to add `()` to its name.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

If you simply do `event.preventDefault`, you are just having the reference to the function.